# Run python script on webserver (background)

Tags: python, webserver, cpanel

I am currently creating a script that makes "statistics" and it has to run continually, and I would like to upload it on my webserver (it has cPanel) to run on it, and not on my computer. I want it to run in backround so I don't need to open any webpage or anyhting else. Is that possible?

Comment: You could use a cron job perhaps? https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/what-are-cron-jobs

Comment: @chrisbyte so i should create a cron job that run "python script.py" just once (because my script never stop)?

Comment: @luskbo has provided a better answer I believe, although you could also use cgi-bin to host the script on a web server, depending on what host you have and what access they allow https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-create-a-cgi-bin-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supervisor is a good way to do this.

http://supervisord.org/
This allows you to run the script at boot just like a service. 
Also allows you to specify command line options and specify logging. 
Has options for auto restart.

Example config:

```
[program:test]
command=/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/test.py
directory=/home/ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/test.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/test.out.log
user=ubuntu
```

If you are looking to run it in the context of the web server, you might also looking to to Django, which is a Python web framework for web sites / applications.
Then you could use Celery to schedule your Python functions.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html